# ST-LINK and PA13,14 Pins on STM32F407

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, gpio, stm32f4, st-link

If I use PA13,14 pins for flashing my MCU via ST-LINK programmer then can I also use these pins as GPIO in the same circuit? Will that not disturb the ST-Link if some analog or digital circuit is connected with these pins? Also if I use these pins as GPIO inputs then how will the MCU know if the input signal is for GPIO or for flashing the MCU from ST-Link?

Comment: 5 questions about the STM32 in as many hours, it would probably be worth while to spend a little more time reading the documentation compared to posting.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes I am doing it side by side.. and its highly helpful to get input from experienced people here in parallel to my own reading. I hope I am not violating any rules of the forum here.

Comment: Actually, you are.  Questions should be researched yourself *before* posting, and show *evidence* of that research in the question.  What have you already tried?  How thoroughly have you read the *existing* questions here related to this?  (The essence of your current question has in fact come up many times here before, usually in the course of people having locked themselves out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use PA13,14 pins for flashing my MCU via ST-LINK programmer then can I also use these pins as GPIO in the same circuit?

No. Configuring these pins for SWD (alternate function AF0) will make them unavailable as GPIOs.

Comment: They can be (read: always are) SWD during reset and then GPIO after boot.

Comment: @BenVoigt True. That'd require NRST to be connected to the debugger, though -- and, obviously, it'd make debugging impossible.